# conversation.getWorkspace is not a function?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to get details of conversation workspace. I am using node and the getWorkspace API as mentioned in this reference [doc](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#get_workspace)

When I run the `conversation.getWorkspace()` function, I get the error - `conversation.getWorkspace is not a function`.

Is this a deprecated API? Any suggestion on how I can get the status of a workspace using the watson-developer-cloud package?

Comment: Are you using the Node SDK? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk

Comment: yes, i am. using the package watson-developer-cloud

Comment: oh i see. i have an older version of the package (v1.12.4) and i see in my local file that this function is not part of the class. let me update and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js functions for managing IBM Watson Conversation Service workspaces and its included objects can be found in the [Watson Developer Cloud Node SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk). Make sure to be on the latest version to get the full functions. Note that the version needs to be set as part of initializing the API.

Comment: i was using an old version (v1.12.4) updating to v2 works. thank you!